# Available Facebook Share Dialogs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a FB canvas app that has share functionality, my plan is to use `FB.ui()` dialos for this purpose.

My research came up with two methods of doing this:

- [the send dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) which allows sharing as a private message
- [the feed dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) which allows sharing on the wall/timeline

however, when i share a link via my time line i get a more the more advanced dialog which allows many different options of sharing (having several options, timeline, friends timeline, group, page or private message) [image: timeline share]

**My Question:** Is there any way of geting the advanced share dialog in my own app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redirect users to the old share pages, or display this in a popup.

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[url]&t=[title]
```

This is slightly less flexible than FB.ui - no action links etc. But, it does give you those advanced sharing options.